# Paperclip, fog.io and Rackspace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rackspace, fog

I'm trying to find documentations on how to setup Paperclip to use fog.io and fog.io to use Rackspace Cloud File, but I wasn't able to find any good reference (and I consider myself a good Google language speaker :D). The ideal scenario would be a setup where I could use local storage for a development environment and Rackspace for production.

Could anyone point to a good doc or use this space to document this approach?

Tks!

**== Update ==:**

Paperclip to fog.io

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/storage/fog.rb

fog.io to Rackspace Cloud File

http://fog.io/storage/

... still trying to figure out how to put these together.

Comment: http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/04/16/using-rackspace-cloudfiles-with-paperclip/ checkout this link

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I got it.

On config/initializers/paperclip_defaults.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.update({
  :path => "images/:class/:id/:attachment/:style/img_:fingerprint",
  :storage => :fog,
  :fog_credentials => {
    :provider           => 'Rackspace',
    :rackspace_username => 'blablabla',
    :rackspace_api_key  => 'blablabla',
    :persistent => false
  },
  :fog_directory => 'blablabla',
  :fog_public => true,
  :fog_host => 'http://blablabla.rackcdn.com'
})
```

where...

**:fog_directory** - This is your Rackspace Cloud File container.

**:fog_host** - The Cloud File CDN URL

**:persistent** - To prevent a bug on Fog/Excon. You may not need this on the future.

Also use **:fingerprint** paperclip feature to avoid CDN cache when you update the file.

Comment: Worked great. I did not need to include fog_host.

Comment: I am using the same paperclip_defaults.rb settings you mentioned above.

I have added gem 'fog' to my gemfile. 

but when I do require 'fog' on console, it return False.

I actually am trying to read the file I just uploaded to Rackspace on rails console.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Ketan: Bundler already attempts to require fog when it loads. If it loads successfully and you try to load it again, the require command will return false.